# Bounded derivative function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Prove that $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R\\
x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$                                  is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=0$, thus $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank's for your answer and editing my question.